# Quartz.aspnetcore and hosting in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz.net

When we use Quartz.AspNetCore with ASP.NET Core 6, there are two ways to host it in the server:

```
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    
});

builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
{
    // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

But we can do it as well with

```
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    
});

builder.Services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
{
    // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

what difference between `AddQuartzServer` and `AddQuartzHostedService`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [article](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html#a-practical-example-of-the-setup), you could find the `AddQuartz` is used to add base Quartz scheduler, job and trigger configuration(configure and register the `IScheduler` instance and its related services with the `ASP.NET Core` dependency injection container).

The `AddQuartzServer` is used to configure how it works with asp.net core process , it configure and register a hosted service that starts and stops the `IScheduler` instance automatically when the `ASP.NET Core` application starts and stops.

It registers `QuartzHostedService` as a hosted service with the `ASP.NET Core` dependency injection container.

---

The `AddQuartzServer` call the `AddQuartzHostedService`, the `AddQuartzServer` will call the HealthChecks to check the scheduler health.

Source code like this:

```
using System;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

#if SUPPORTS_HEALTH_CHECKS
using Quartz.AspNetCore.HealthChecks;
#endif

namespace Quartz
{
    public static class QuartzServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddQuartzServer(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            Action<QuartzHostedServiceOptions>? configure = null)
        {
#if SUPPORTS_HEALTH_CHECKS
            services
                .AddHealthChecks()
                .AddTypeActivatedCheck<QuartzHealthCheck>("quartz-scheduler");
#endif

            return services.AddQuartzHostedService(configure);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: appologize. I corrected my question.
I was asking what the difference between AddQuartzServer and AddQuartzHostedService.
Seems they both the same

Comment: The AddQuartzServer call the AddQuartzHostedService, the AddQuartzServer will call the  HealthChecks to check the scheduler health. Details, you could see my update souce codes example.